# swagerUi adding token globally to Authorize in swagger ui

Tags: javascript, swagger, swagger-ui, nodejs-server

I have added header in individual route for sending token but what i am trying is , adding token in Authorize in swagger ui once so that I don't have to send token in header in every individual route.[image]

I have tried with adding securityDefinitions as show in image but when i console the request object in nodejs server , the header option didnot appeared .

Comment: I think you need to add  the security definition to each route

Comment: Also what is the version of swagger you are using?

Comment: i have been using swagger 2.o version

Comment: As you said if i add security option to each route it works but I am trying to avoid writing token to individual route once we logged in.  Can't we add token once in header and avoid writing token for individual route instead ?

Comment: i don't think swagger docs support that way of authorization.  This was my similar concern but i ended up doing  adding header at each path . Anyway it is dynamic it does not impact on performance. Once you have token you just iterate and add the definition.

Comment: Also show me how are you adding definition to each routes? i can check if there is better way